# Function overloading for string reference and const char pointer

Tags: c++, string

Is it legal to define two class functions, one overloaded with a reference to a `string` and the other overloaded with a `const char*`?

```
void funcA(const std::string& s)
void funcA(const char* s)
```

Can I guarantee that if I call `funcA()` with a `const char*` input, it will not call the string function? I'm asking because there is an implicit construction from a `const char*` to a `string`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's valid. If you pass a `const char*`, the second overload is an exact match, which is preferred over all other overloads, particularly ones involving user-defined conversions (such as converting to a `const std::string`).